# Aptitude Asked in CSIR Exam

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

How to solve this:
If $$D+I+M=1501$$
$$C+I+V+I+L=157$$
$$L+I+V+I+D=557$$
$$C+I+V+I+C=207$$
What Is $V+I+M=?$

Stuck at this! Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ROMAN NUMERALS](http://literacy.kent.edu/Minigrants/Cinci/romanchart.htm)

The letters are the romen numerals so the answer is ;

> $5+1+1000=1006$

Comment: although the answer is correct, I think an answer that would give a step by step solution would be better. Not everyone is familiar with roman numerals and this should be solvable with no knowledge about them

Comment: @IvoBeckers  this can also be solved by matrix multiplication but originally it was prepared to be solved in this way anyway

Comment: Hmm.. thinking about it. if $I = 2$, $V=3$, $M=999$, $C=100$, $D=500$, $L=50$ would also be a solution and then $V + I + M = 1004$. So there are multiple solutions possible. Roman numerals is probably the intended answer but it is not the only possible answer